# How to save timestamp and user in comments column

Tags: php

I have a textarea, where the user can add their comments. Now after adding the comments and clicking submit, it needs to save the comments along with user name and timestamp.

```
<tr><font size="2" face="tahoma" color="black">
<b>Comments </b></br></br> 
</tr>
<textarea name="comments" id= "comments" ROWS="10" Cols = "130"> </textarea> 
<br/><br /><br /><br />
```

Above is my HTML markup for comments and I save the session login username in a variable `$user`.
Now how can I save it along with timestamp and user?

Comment: use session . is this user is a logged in user? then you have the details already. just save to db

Comment: What you actually need, imho, is a `<form>` tag

Comment: Your HTML is incomplete - it would be preferable if you included a valid HTML snippet - **not** the entire page - but at least opening and closing tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first off you need to create a new table in your database named "comment"
Comment will now hold 4 values: id, comment, time, user.

Use an insert query to insert to the database

Comment: The OP is still trying to get the data to the server - your answer *could* be to his next question :)

Comment: he did say that it needs to save the comment, time and user.

Comment: Correct - but there was no reference to databases.  He might be saving the data in XML files for all we know (*shudder*).  Your post is valid but I do not believe that it will help the OP with **this specific** question.  Perhaps pending an edit by the OP your answer will be more helpful.

Comment: true, though we are extremely lacking the details needed to help him/her. also i'm already assuming that he is already knowledgeable in using forms.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the idea. I could crete the comments table with the same id which i am using for saving the other details in forum in another table. So irresepctive of how many comments user add, the id will be same, which can be populated back to the test area using select query.

Answer (score 1):

It was not included in your OP but I am assuming that you have a `<form>` element that posts it's content to a [php](/questions/tagged/php) script.  You can append additional *hidden* fields in your form that will not be displayed to the user - but will be sent off with the rest of the information inside the `<form>` element.

---

You could add the users information in a hidden input field :

```
<input type="hidden" value="{$user_info}"></input>
```

For the timestamp you can call php's `time()` function in the script that receives the form.

Comment: I would not recommend this because it's easily vulnerable to forgery.

Comment: I'd have thought this would be fine (as long as your protecting against xss)

Comment: It is a simple question that I felt could be answered simply.  Security is way out of the scope here.  Any script receiving data originating from a specific user that needs to associate that data to the user would need to have some form of authentication in place.  But essentially you are 100% correct.  To avoid problems one should always remember that you should never trust information coming into your application.  **always always always** validate and sanitate :)